# posting a value and retrieve it in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two fields in a form `category name and id`. The id is an auto increment. After posting the category name, I want that posted category id pass to next page.

I think i am doing some mistake in select statement.

http://pastebin.com/3Tu2Hr6g

Comment: Here it is not selecting that category id as far i know but it is displaying the same id number 5 for which ever new category is added.

Comment: I have accepted answer which is correct.For some questions i found the solution and posted it there.

Comment: category, name and id... That makes 3 to me... not two.

Comment: if you found solution to some of your question. You can answer it yourself and accept it. So that other people who landed on your question vie search engine can benefit it.

Comment: category name and category id so it is only two not three.

Comment: do you see 'Your Answer' on this page? That's where you answer question. Do that to your question in which you found the solution.

Comment: @Silent: I did n't understand your comment.If some body give me correct answer i use to click the correct mark but for my answer that correct box will not be threre.

Comment: your answer will be just like anyone else's answer. you can chose your own answer as best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
"SELECT ThirdPartyCategoryID,'".$ThirdPartyCategoryName."' FROM  thirdpartycategorymaster"
```

you probably want something like this:

```
"SELECT ThirdPartyCategoryID,ThirdPartyCategoryName FROM  thirdpartycategorymaster WHERE ThirdPartyCategoryName='".$ThirdPartyCategoryName."'"
```

And before I forget: PLEASE check and escape user input from HTTP requests before you insert it into your queries. The code you posted is extremely vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your last inserted id using   `mysql_insert_id()`

**Sample...**

```
$res = mysql_query( "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" );

or

$res - mysql_insert_id();
```